# Loop with characters and integers

Tags: python

I'd like to create with a loop from 1 to n a list similar to the following one:

```
['Iteration 1', 'Iteration 2', 'Iteration 3', … 'Iteration n']
```

Comment: Hi! You should provide your attemps to solve your problem; [StackOverflow is not about solving homework without prior attetmps](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For generating a list from 1 to n, we use [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

```
In [8]: n = 10                                                                                                                 

In [9]: for i in range(1,n+1): 
   ...:     print(i) 
   ...:                                                                                                                        
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Building on this, to generate the string you want from 1 to n, we do as follows, we build the string using `string.format`

```
In [10]: for i in range(1,n+1): 
    ...:     print('Iteration {}'.format(i)) 
    ...:                                                                                                                       
Iteration 1
Iteration 2
Iteration 3
Iteration 4
Iteration 5
Iteration 6
Iteration 7
Iteration 8
Iteration 9
Iteration 10
```

Combining the ideas above, The last thing needed is to append all these in a list using `list.append`

```
In [11]: li = []                                                                                                               

In [12]: for i in range(1,n+1): 
    ...:     li.append('Iteration {}'.format(i)) 
    ...:                                                                                                                       

In [13]: li                                                                                                                    
Out[13]: 
['Iteration 1',
 'Iteration 2',
 'Iteration 3',
 'Iteration 4',
 'Iteration 5',
 'Iteration 6',
 'Iteration 7',
 'Iteration 8',
 'Iteration 9',
 'Iteration 10']
```

This is how I would think of solving the problems in steps, although you can do all this is a single-line of list-comprehension

```
In [14]: li = ['Iteration {}'.format(i) for i in range(1,11)]                                                                  

In [15]: li                                                                                                                    
Out[15]: 
['Iteration 1',
 'Iteration 2',
 'Iteration 3',
 'Iteration 4',
 'Iteration 5',
 'Iteration 6',
 'Iteration 7',
 'Iteration 8',
 'Iteration 9',
 'Iteration 10']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer, it was really useful.

Comment: No worries! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
foo = list()
for i in range(1, n+1):
    foo.append('Iteration {}'.format(i))
```

Comment: you may need `range(1, n+1)` or `format(i+1)`. And you forgot `)` after `.format(i)`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can do this. I use a lambda function and list comprehension

```
create_list = lambda n: ['iteration {}'.format(i) for i in range(1, n+1)]
mylist = create_list(10)
print(mylist)
```

Result:

```
['iteration 1', 'iteration 2', 'iteration 3', 'iteration 4', 'iteration 5', 'iteration 6', 'iteration 7', 'iteration 8', 'iteration 9', 'iteration 10']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
n=int(input("enter number :"))
output = [ "iteration "+str(i) for i in range(1,n+1)]
print(output)
```